# Google Play Billing interrupted purcahse: Billing result response code is ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, android-billing, play-billing-library

I have a scenario with the Google Play Billing library version **2.0.1** when I interrupt an in-app purchase, the scenario is as follows:

1. User clicks on a button to purchase a subscription from the Android app.
2. While the Google Play progress dialog is shown, the internet connection is interrupted.
3. Google Play shows a "Connection timeout" error dialog.

When the user clicks on the button to purchase again and the billing flow starts, Google responds with a dialog with the message:

> "Your order is processing, your item will be available in a few
>   minutes"

The problem is that the user sees the subscription in the "Subscriptions" screen in the Google Play app, but since that purchase was not acknowledged, the purchase will be refunded after 3 days.

I'm trying to find a way to detect this scenario, the only thing I found is that my `PurchasesUpdatedListener.onPurchasesUpdated` returns an empty purchases list `List<Purchase>` and a `BillingResult` with the `responseCode` `ITEM_ALREADY_OWNED`

Also querying previous purchases via `queryPurchaseHistoryAsync` returns that the purchase is acknowledged (which didn't happen because the flow was interrupted).

I found a similar issue on the sample app repo on Github: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-billing/issues/127

But I'm wondering if there is a real solution to the issue?

Comment: Did you find any solution to this, I am also experiencing the same problem.

Comment: @AmeerFaisal no not really, I didn't find any updates. Did you try the latest version of the library?

Comment: Are you working with the sample containing firebase backend server?

Comment: @NamikazeMinato No it's another sample, would Firebase make a difference?

Comment: I think it can be much safer with the server (acknowledging the purchases on the server, not sharing any keys, etc.). And google "highly recommends" using the backend server. It also provides some good analytic info. I have set it up according to the sample and tested it but it has some problems. If you are interested, you can join and help to fix the issues. Apparently google devs don't care about updating the sample.

Comment: I am a bit concerned about the safety. Everyone prefers to work without the backend server anyway. Do you suggest me any of the security practices here? https://developer.android.com/topic/security/best-practices

Comment: I totally agree that backend validation and acknowledgment is the best way, but it's not feasible to small teams and individual developers. So what I'd do is whenever one of those scenarios happen, I'd fire a job scheduler or work manager task to retry acknowledging purchases.